# Stored Procedure for UPSERT functionality

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, plsql

Below is my table in which `ID column is Primary Key`. And other two columns are string.

I am using a new Database named `XpressMP`.

```
Column Name                
-------
ID             PrimaryKey                 
SEARCHES       String
ACCOUNT        String
```

I am trying to achieve functionality of `UPSERT` here-

```
If ID doesn't exists here then insert a new record.
And ID exists then update the record.
```

I know If I am working with Oracle then I can use `MERGE` sql command but `MERGE` is not supported in that database and there is no other command for that as of now. But I believe I can do the same thing with `Stored Procedure`.

Can anyone provide some suggestions how can I do the same thing with Stored Procedure? As stored procedure will work there.

**UPDATED:-**

```
public final static String INSERT = "BEGIN"
+" INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, SEARCHES, ACCOUNT) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
+" EXCEPTION"
+" WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN"
+" UPDATE TABLE"
+" SET SEARCHES = ?, ACCOUNT = ?"
+" WHERE ID = ?"
+" END";
```

Whenever I try to execute the above stored procedure like this

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(INSERT);

preparedStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(userId));
preparedStatement.setString(2, Constants.getaAccount(userId));
preparedStatement.setString(3, Constants.getaAdvertising(userId));
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

I get exception? Is this the right way to execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it using the `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` exception.
You can add the below code in your procedure, which should meet your requirement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLE_UPSERT (v_id IN NUMBER,
                                          v_searches IN VARCHAR2(20),
                                          v_account IN VARCHAR2(20)) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table (id, searches, account) VALUES (v_id, v_searches, v_account) ;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    UPDATE TABLE
    SET searches = v_searches, account = v_account
    WHERE id = v_id;
END;
/
```

You can read more about DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX Exception [here](http://www.oraclecity.com/oracle-faq/what-is-ora-00001-dup_val_on_index-error/) and [here](http://psoug.org/definition/DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX.htm).

---

Another option would be to insert or update the data after checking the count.

```
DECLARE
  l_count number;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) 
  INTO l_count
  FROM table 
  WHERE id = (value);

  IF l_count = 0 THEN
    INSERT into table VALUES ....;
  ELSE
    UPDATE table SET searches = .., account = ..;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Orangecrush for the help. Will take a look into `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX`. As I will be using java to call this stored procedure. So I modfiied your SP something like this to work. `BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, SEARCHES, ACCOUNT) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    UPDATE TABLE
    SET SEARCHES = ?, ACCOUNT = ?
    WHERE ID = ?;
END;`. It should work right? As I filling ... with ? mark.

Comment: @FarhanJamal Yes, should work provided you handle the variable properly in java while calling this procedure. Give it a try. Have also given edited and provied a simpler-to-understand code, if you want to try that one. But I would suggest using `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX`.

Comment: @FarhanJamal I presume that you'll call this SP from java using `SP (?,?,?)`. You cannot use `?` for a variable value in a PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: I updated the question with more details. I guess, I am doing wrong and that is the reason I am getting exception. Let me know if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Aaah.. Now makes sense so that means, I need to execute this stored procedure firstly so that it gets created in the database and then I need to call it from Java program. Right? So how can i create this stored procedure in my database?

Comment: @FarhanJamal I am not good with Java, I'm afraid, so cannot suggest. An alternate that I can however give is to create the procedure in the Oracle DB like the one that I have provided in the answer (edited now - might have syntax errors as I do not have DB here to check). Once this is created, all you need to do in java is to call this procedure `TABLE_UPSERT` with the parameters `id`, `searches` and `account` and the procedure takes care of everything. Good enough?

Comment: @FarhanJamal To create procedure in database - just copy paste the code in my answer in a text file and save it as filename.sql. Login to your DB schema using sqlplus or developer and in the sql prompt enter "@filename.sql". The procedure will get created (if syntax is right - else you need to tweak it a bit). P.S: Change the tablename and the datatype (number, varchar2(20)), as per your design in filename.sql before running the file in sqlplus/developer.

Answer (score 2):

i agree with @tabish here. you'll have to do it the traditional way. 
the way you suggested i think your causing more harm - you perform an insert for each row in the source table (to either the target table or to the ERR table) and then performing an additional update. 
in the worst case, when you have to update all the rows, **you would perform twice as much dml operations.**
this is not a good idea in my book.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you have to do it in a traditional way.

IF ROW DOESN'T EXIST
INSERT
ELSE 
UPDATE

Comment: Yeah I know that already :). But what is that traditional way? Stored Procedures right?

Comment: Its your design decision .i will recommended Stored Procedure.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am also thinking. Can you provide me any example related to stored procedure that will work in my case?