# MySQL UPSERT without ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: php, mysql, database, upsert

I want a `UPSERT` (`UPDATE` if exists, else insert) on a MySQL table with these fields:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
  uid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  timestamp int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  category1 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  category2 int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  counter int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
)
```

This table is already in productive use, and the combination of `(timestamp,category1,category2)` is for my `INSERT` unique, but not for the whole table content. That's the reason why I can't use the "**ON DUPLICATE KEY**" feature.

For clarification about the UNIQUE problem:
If category1=9 then this is my insert, and `(timestamp,category1,category2)` is unique. But the table is in productive use, and if category1=1,2 then `(timestamp,category1,category2)` is not unique. 
As far as I know I can't add a `UNIQUE` key, as it would create problems with the categories 1+2.

What I need is something like this:

```
 IF (timestamp,category1,category2) exists 
     counter=existingCount + newCount
 ELSE 
     insert new record
```

I use PHP and MySQL, so any combination of both languages is fine.

What I tried already, but takes too much time is:

- Single PHP `SELECT` statement, then `UPDATE` or `INSERT`
- `INSERT` everything then `UPDATE` and `DELETE` duplicate rows

Thanks to answers I created now this Stored Procedure, syntax is OK but procedure is not working:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myUpsert;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE myUpsert (IN v_timestamp INT, IN v_category1 INT, IN v_category2 INT, IN v_counter INT)        
BEGIN
  DECLARE existingCounter INT;
  SELECT COUNT(counter) AS existingCounter from item 
  WHERE timestamp =v_timestamp  AND category1=v_category1 AND category2=v_category2;

  IF existingCounter=0 THEN
    INSERT INTO item (timestamp,category1,category2,counter) 
    VALUES (v_timestamp,v_category1,v_category2,v_counter);
  ELSE
    UPDATE item SET count=v_counter+existingCounter
    WHERE timestamp=v_timestamp AND category1=v_category1 AND category2=v_category2;
  END IF;
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: can you show the ***code*** you tried please? not just a description of it

Comment: INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY ?

Comment: Is there a combination of columns in your table that _is_ unique? If so, add a `UNIQUE` key for them and use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: Are the records you want to insert/update in a table?

Comment: have you tried doing an upsert Stored Procedure if the single select + (insert or update) is too slow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785155/stored-procedure-for-upsert-functionality

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I get insert data from another database, do some stuff in PHP, and then write it to this one

Comment: @NicolasMarengo: see edited Question, could use some help on the stored procedure syntax, this is not working

Comment: Are you sure your timestamp column is int and not timestamp?

Comment: @NicolasMarengo: yes timestamp is int, return value from time()

Comment: @Andrea you are not setting existingCounter = the select statement...? see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myUpsert;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE myUpsert (IN v_timestamp INT, IN v_category1 INT, IN v_category2 INT, IN v_counter INT)        
BEGIN
DECLARE existingCounter INT;
  SET existingCounter = (SELECT COUNT(counter) from item 
  WHERE timestamp =v_timestamp  AND category1=v_category1 AND category2=v_category2);

IF existingCounter=0 THEN
 INSERT INTO item (timestamp,category1,category2,counter) 
 VALUES (v_timestamp,v_category1,v_category2,v_counter);
ELSE
 UPDATE item SET count=v_counter+existingCounter
 WHERE timestamp=v_timestamp AND category1=v_category1 AND category2=v_category2;
 END IF;
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Or you could have also done (INTO)
..."SELECT COUNT(counter) INTO existingCounter from"....

Comment: This will not work under concurrent access.  See the excellent summary at http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a unique index for those three columns:

ALTER TABLE item ADD UNIQUE (timestamp, category1, category2)

Comment: I believe OP indicated that set of columns is not unique in the table.