# sql REPLACE WHERE two foreign fields

Tags: mysql, replace, sql-update, sql-insert

I need to replace 'text', when my combination of non-primary fields (user1 and user2) exist in table. Or insert new row user1, user2, text - when doesn't.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS opinions 
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
user1 INT, user2 INT, text TEXT);

+----+-----------+-----------+----------+
| id | user1     | user2     | text     |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | 141015727 | 627964361 | nice guy |
|  2 | 141015727 | 375392538 | hello    |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Expected output:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+----------+
| id | user1     | user2     | text     |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | 141015727 | 627964361 | bad guy  |
|  2 | 141015727 | 375392538 | hello    |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

UPD

mysql> select * from opinions;

```
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
| id | user1     | user2     | text   |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
|  1 | 141015727 | 627964361 | hello1 |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

Expected output

```
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
| id | user1     | user2     | text   |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
|  1 | 141015727 | 627964361 | hello2 |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

Tried (sorry, seems like i deleted this answer by mistake)

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT user1, user2 FROM opinions WHERE user1=\'141015727\' 
AND user2 = \'627964361\') THEN UPDATE opinions SET text = \'hello2\' 
WHERE user1 = \'141015727\' AND user2 = \'627964361\' 
ELSE INSERT INTO opinions (user1, user2, text) 
VALUES (\'141015727\', \'627964361\', \'hello2\') END IF;'
```

got an error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT user1, user2 FROM opinions WHERE user1='141015727' AND user2 = '
```

Comment: seems like i deleted someone's answer by a mistake. Sorry, i'm new here

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: "seems like i deleted someone's answer by a mistake. Sorry, i'm new here" you can't refresh the page

Comment: updated expected output in question

Comment: i editted mine answer (on the bottom) with a more simple query with MySQL user variables (queries are in the db-fiddles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1)**

You can create a stored procedure that check for existence of **user_1** and **user_2** values and in case of duplicate do an update, otherwise an insert. I'm not going to enter on a detailed description here, you can read about stored procedures if you are interested. For your basic example, i will go like in next option.

**Option 2)**

First, we create an unique index on the table you have:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS opinions (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user1 INT,
    user2 INT,
    text TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT uniqueUsersTuple UNIQUE (user1, user2)
);
```

Then, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO opinions (user1, user2, text)
VALUES (userID1, userID2, "newOpinion")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE text = "newOpinion";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your where condition is not on the primary key.  Unfortunately, You cannot do in 1 query.

See this post : [MySQL UPSERT without ON DUPLICATE KEY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639414/mysql-upsert-without-on-duplicate-key)

Answer (score 0):

Or this badboy method if you don't want to create a extra unique key. 
You know every indexes slows down UPDATE and DELETE query a bit more, so if you do alot off writes to your tables this might outperform D.Smania answer to so some degree.

**When the record exists**

**Query**

```
REPLACE INTO 
 opinions (
     id
   , user1
   , user2
   , opinion
)

SELECT 
   id
 , user1
 , user2
 , opinion
FROM (

  SELECT
     id
   , user1
   , user2
   , 'bad guy' AS opinion
   , (@found := 1) AS found
  FROM
   opinions
  WHERE
     user1 = 141015727
   AND
     user2 = 627964361

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT
    DISTINCT
       null AS id
     , 141015727 AS user1
     , 627964361 AS user2
     , 'bad guy' AS opinion
     , (@found := 0) AS found  
  FROM
   opinions
  WHERE 
    @found <> 1  
) AS alias
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @found := 0) AS init_var_params
```

**Result**

```
| id  | user1     | user2     | opinion |
| --- | --------- | --------- | ------- |
| 1   | 141015727 | 627964361 | bad guy |
| 2   | 141015727 | 375392538 | hello   |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jqsEc1FBBAd4QW3HdNKcj/1)

**When the record does not exists**

**Query**

```
REPLACE INTO 
 opinions (
     id
   , user1
   , user2
   , opinion
)

SELECT 
   id
 , user1
 , user2
 , opinion
FROM (

  SELECT
     id
   , user1
   , user2
   , 'bad guy' AS opinion
   , (@found := 1) AS found
  FROM
   opinions
  WHERE
     user1 = 100
   AND
     user2 = 100

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT
    DISTINCT
       null AS id
     , 100 AS user1
     , 100 AS user2
     , 'bad guy' AS opinion
     , (@found := 0) AS found  
  FROM
   opinions
  WHERE 
    @found <> 1  
) AS alias
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @found := 0) AS init_var_params
```

**Result**

```
| id  | user1     | user2     | opinion  |
| --- | --------- | --------- | -------- |
| 1   | 141015727 | 627964361 | nice guy |
| 2   | 141015727 | 375392538 | hello    |
| 3   | 100       | 100       | bad guy  |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jqsEc1FBBAd4QW3HdNKcj/1)

**Edited**

I made use off MySQL user variables with some adjusting this does also be possible to do without MySQL  user variables. So other databases systems with a REPLACE or other UPSET method could also use this method.

**Existing** 
[Without MySQL user variables View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jqsEc1FBBAd4QW3HdNKcj/2)

**Non existing** 
[Without MySQL user variables View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jqsEc1FBBAd4QW3HdNKcj/4)

Comment: thanks. It's too complicated for my level. If i wasn't such newbie i would just use 2 requests, as i don't need the same  unique IDs. Figured it out right now

Answer (score 0):

If i wasn't such a newbie i would just make 2 requests, as **i didn't need unique IDs to remain the same**. Figured it out right now.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS opinions 
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
user1 INT, user2 INT, text TEXT);

DELETE FROM opinions WHERE user1='1' AND user2='2';
INSERT INTO opinions (user1, user2, text) VALUES ('1','2','bad guy');
```

it was SO EASY